# Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space with $\partial A = \varnothing$. Show that $A$ is both open and closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

**Question**

I had a go at trying to prove an exersice in my book "Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space with $bd(A) =  \emptyset$. Show that $A$ is both open and closed" and came up with something that is a bit repetitive and feels like is could be incorrect. There are no answers (as usual) and I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice. I know this was answered over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448064/show-that-the-boundary-of-a-is-empty-iff-a-is-closed-and-open) but  they used a method that was not discussed so I want to prove it without using that method.

**Attempted Proof**

Let $bd(A) =  \emptyset$ and let $X$ be our metric space with $A \subseteq X$

thus $bd(A) =\bar {A} \cap \overline{ X \backslash A} = \emptyset$

as $X \backslash A \subseteq \overline{ X \backslash A}$

we have $\bar {A} \cap X \backslash A \subseteq\bar {A} \cap \overline{ X \backslash A} = \emptyset$

thus $\bar {A} \cap X \backslash A = \emptyset$

$\implies$ there exists a nbd $N$ of $x \in X \backslash A $ such that $N \cap A = \emptyset$

thus $N \subseteq X \backslash A$ making $x$ an interior point of $X \backslash A$

thus $X \backslash A$ is open making $A$ closed

Similarly

as $A \subseteq \bar {A}$

thus $A \cap \overline{ X \backslash A} \subseteq \bar {A} \cap \overline{ X \backslash A} = \emptyset$

thus $A \cap \overline{ X \backslash A}= \emptyset$

$\implies$ there exists a nbd $N$ of $a \in A $ such that $N \cap X \backslash A = \emptyset$

thus $N \subseteq A$ making making $a$ an interior point of $A$

thus $A$ is open

This completes the attempted proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an useful identity to solve the proposed exercise:
\begin{align*}
X = \text{int}(A)\cup\partial A\cup\text{ext}(A)
\end{align*}

Where $(X,d_{X})$ is the underlying metric space.

Once $\partial A = \varnothing$, one concludes that $X = \text{int}(A)\cup\text{ext}(A)$, whose union is disjoint.

Moreover, it is also valid to conclude that
\begin{align*}
A = A\cap X = A\cap(\text{int}(A)\cup\text{ext}(A)) = A\cap\text{int}(A) \Rightarrow A\subset\text{int}(A).
\end{align*}

Given the relation $\text{int}(A)\subset A$ always holds, one deduces that $A = \text{int}(A)$.

From this, it results that $A$ is open.

Finally, we get that $A^{c} = X\backslash A = X\backslash\text{int}(A) = \text{ext}(A)$, which implies the desired claim.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you, your proof is so nice and "clean". In my proof I made some wild use of $\subseteq$ that I am not comfortable that I used them correctly. Can they be used like that or did I butcher the whole proof?